# Moving Data Between Folders on Server

Tags: directory

Lets say I have a server and 2 folders for 2 seperate domains

Domain A
Domain B

I have files in Domain A that I want to move to Domain B. I could either download them from Domain B to my computer and upload them again. It takes time to download and upload. However, the other option is to log into the server administration panel and the file mangager and use the "move" option that the server admin panel provides. In general, is the speed faster moving files on the server within folders?

Is it a similar process to moving files between folders on your own computer? The files are about 2 Gig's in size and I am wondering how long you would predict that taking. My host is ixwebhosting.com and I have a 12 dollar a month plan. Shared hosting basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are moving files between folders on the same server, then it would be much, much faster to use the copy command in your control panel. This involves disk transfer and not network transfer.

Yes, it is similar to a local folder transfer on your own computer.

Make sure you do have a local backup of your files though, or you will kick yourself when the hosting company inevitable suspends your account or goes down.

Comment: yeah this pretty much answers my question. Thanks everyone for helping out. Both folders are on the same server so I assumed it was similar to what you said. I am currently downloading the files to have a local backup. 

Where you saying " when the hosting company inevitable suspends your account or goes down." in general? Or because I am transferring 2 gigs between folders?

Comment: Just in general, move command doesn't involve too much disk i/o.

Answer (score 1):

Have you contacted your hosting provider for advice? They would be in the best position to tell you the best option since they ought to know the ins and outs of their setup better than anyone on SF.

Comment: Plus most hosting providers offer a transfer service, often for free. +1

Answer (score 0):

I you are talking about using Microsoft's file sharing service then by copying the files from Domain A to Domain B using a third computer will cause all files to be essentially copied 2 times.  Once from Domain A to the third computer and once from the third computer to Domain B.

The best choice is to use a tool that initiates the copy/ move from the server for Domain A.  It sounds like that server admin tool will work great.

As for the transfer through ixwebhosting.com -- It looks like you have unlimited transfers a month but you will have to know how fast your connection is from Domain A to Domain B to calculate the time.

I usually do a Google search for [bandwidth calculator](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=bandwidth+calc).

Comment: I thought this at first too, but from the question I think both of his sites are on one server, eg one is in /home/user/domains/domain.com, and the other is /home/user/domains/domain2.com.